# Sign tests on median sex ratios grouped by species in R

Tags: r

I have the sex ratios `(M / M + F)` of the offspring of ~35,000 mother birds from >400 species organized in this manner:

| IOC_species | DamID | SR |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Acanthis_flammea | 3579601 | 0.333333333 |
| Accipiter_gentilis | 3431823 | 0.333333333 |
| Accipiter_gentilis | 3109836 | 0.4 |
| Accipiter_gentilis | 3824842 | 0.636363636 |
| Accipiter_nisus | 542070 | 0.5 |
| Accipiter_nisus | 4006664 | 0.5 |
| Acridotheres_burmannicus | 2207112 | 1 |
| Acridotheres_burmannicus | 947697 | 0.666666667 |
| Acridotheres_burmannicus | 10101 | 0.833333333 |
| Acridotheres_cristatellus | 920019 | 0.333333333 |

I want to calculate the median sex ratio per species and then use a statistic to see if this differs significantly from 50/50. My current plan is to use a one-sample sign test in the `DescTools` package on R. Here is the code I've been using:

```
library(DescTools)
data <- read.csv(file.choose())
df <- data.frame(Species=data$IOC_species,SR=data$SR)
sumstats = df %>% group_by (Species) %>%
summarise (medianSR = median(SR), signtest = SignTest (SR,mu=.5),.groups='drop'))
```

When I do this I get the following error message:

```
Error in `summarise()`:
! Problem while computing `signtest = SignTest(SR, mu = 0.5), .groups =
  "drop")`.
x `signtest` must be a vector, not a `htest` object.
i The error occurred in group 1: Species = "Acanthis_flammea".
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

I'm not sure where to go from here - as might be obvious I am fairly new to RStudio. Ideally, I want my answers formatted in a summary table with species names, medians, n's, and sign test p-values.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: This has nothing to do with `RStudio` which is a graphical user interface, not R. The error message indicates that the `signtest=` argument in `summarize()` wants a vector, not an `htest` object which is what `SignTest()` returns. Without a reproducible example, it is difficult to be more specific.

Comment: @dcarlson right so my question is how to conduct a sign test on median species values in an ungrouped dataset of individual values. What kind of reproducible example would you need?

Comment: Enough sample (or made up) data to generate the error message. +/- 10 observations each from 2 or 3 species.

Comment: Please see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example on how to make a reproducible example in R